# Using continuity to find a neighbourhood of a certain kind

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am self studying Edwards's Advanced Calculus of Several Variables and I'm stuck in the Motivation part after the Theorem is stated: [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75sfd.png).

Edwards supposes $D_2G(a,b)>0$. Taking $\varepsilon = D_2G(a,b)/2$, continuity of $D_2G(a,b)$ guarantees us that there is a $\delta >0$ such that for all $(x,y)$ satisfying $|x-a|\le \delta$ and $|y-b|\le \delta$ such that $D_2G(x,y)>D_2G(a,b)/2>0$. We have got an rectangle now. In this case, we can take $c_1=a-\delta, c_2=a+\delta$. Now how does choose $d_1$ and $d_2$ and use the continuity of $G$ such that $G(x,d_1) >0$ for all $x\in[c_1, c_2]$ and $G(x,d_2) >0$ for all $x\in[c_1, c_2]$ ? The obvious choice of $d_1$ and $d_2$ may seem $b-\delta$ and $b+\delta$ but how do I use the definition to prove it?

**Note that by $D_2 G$, Edwards means $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}$.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $D_2 g (a,b)>0$ $\implies $ there is a neighbourhood $R\ni (a,b)$ such that $D_2g(x,y)>0$ for $(x,y) \in R$, because of the continuity of $Dg$. Since $R$ is a neighbourhood you may assume it is an open rectangle about $(a,b)$.
2. Now, since $D_2 g (a,b)>0$ and $G(a,b)=0$ we have $G(a,b+h)>0$ for $0<h < H_+$ for some $H_+$, and $G(a,b-h)>0$ for $0<h < H_-$ for some $H_-$.
3. Choose small enough $0<h_+ < H_+$ and $0<h_- < H_-$ such that $(a,b+h_+), (a,b-h_-)\in R$.
4. By the continuity of $G$ we have $G>0$ in a neighbourhood $B_+$ of $(a,b+{h}_+)$, and $G<0$ in a neighbourhood $B_-$ of $(a,b-{h}_-)$, and by taking their intersection with $R$ you may assume $B_+,B_-\subseteq R$.
5. Now you can choose a small enough $\delta>0$ such that both $\{(a+x,b+{h}_+),|x|\leq \delta\}\subseteq B_+$ and $\{(a+x,b-{h}_-),|x|\leq \delta\}\subseteq B_-$, so that you have your rectangle.